# Extending a div border outside wrap?

Tags: border

[Here is my site](http://www.kerrymkt.com)

Currently still fiddling around with design layout and there is one problem I can't quite solve.
On my header I have a red border-bottom to separate it from the main content. Likewise, on the footer I have a red top-border to do the same. Is there a way of extending the borders beyond the div (and consequently outside of the wrapper, with overflow visible) without it conflicting with the other elements? I want to configure the layout so it has more of a grid-like design.

```
#wrap {
width: 1000px;
background-color: #ffffff;
text-align:left;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
border-left: 1px solid #000000;
border-right: 1px solid #000000; }

#head{
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 1000px;
height: 159px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000; }
```

kind of like [this](http://www.kerrymkt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Screen-shot-2012-08-10-at-13.53.00.png)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can set a negative margin, causing the div to extend outside of its parent, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/taDpY/12/embedded/result/). (I only did the header, but you get the idea)

The solution in the fiddle uses the annoying !important to get the styling right - you might want to reorganize your CSS to get around this and make your code more maintainable, see [this post](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: Thank you, that's worked brilliantly! I do plan on tidying up the CSS at a later point so hopefully I can streamline the code.